# Filtering files in svelte

Tags: file, filtering, svelte

recently i followed some posts on stack overlflow about import some files in svelte, and this is the code:

```
<script>

    let files = [];
    
    function contentArray(ev){
        files = [...files, ...ev.target.files.filter(f => !files.includes(f))]
    }
    </script>
    
    
    <input type='file' multiple on:change={contentArray} accept=".txt">
    {#each files as file}
        <p>The imported file is: {file.name}</p>
    {#await file.text() then text}
        <pre>{text}</pre>
    {/await}
    {/each}
```

My goal is when I import a file, if I try to import it again, the program simply don't show it. I tried with the `filter` method but it gives me this error:

```
ev.target.files.filter is not a function or its return variable is not iterable
```

I searched a bit online, but i cannot understand where i made a mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ev.target.files` is not an array but a `FileList` ([FileList docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)) and, as such, doesn't have the `filter()` method.

So, to use `filter()`, you have to convert the `FileList` to an array first which you can do like this:

```
let arrayFileList = [...ev.target.files];

// now you can arrayFileList.filter(...)
```

Also, comparing the `File` objects when you do `!files.includes(f)` might not give you the desired result depending on your setup. So you might still end up with the same file multiple times. This is because when adding the same file multiple times to your `<input type="file">`, the corresponding `File` instances might not be the same. So you might want to compare based on the name as in

```
arrayFileList.filter(f => !files.some(ff => ff.name === f.name));
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help but if I import a file named "test1", then "test2" and again "test1" i see the content of  "test1" twice... how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried all my suggestions, particularly the last one with comparing the name?

Comment: Yes but maybe I made a mistake somewhere else... here is the program right now: https://svelte.dev/repl/9304e104d7f94f1498f47269e3671c80?version=3.38.2 (so you can run and edit it if you want)

Comment: Great you've used the repl. There were a couple of bugs. [Fixed Version here](https://svelte.dev/repl/e8ccd9b01cb24129addd0411b539d8ed?version=3.38.2). Most important bug: `filter()` doesn't modify the array it's called on, it returns a new, filtered, array. And I fixed the chance that `File.text()` gets called multiple times for the same file in re-renders.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! And thanks for all the explanations and the patience.